# Node app management complaining about missing start script

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I have a node.js app that is pushing successfully into bluemix.

I'm trying to use the App Management feature.

But when I push I get the following warning.

> ```
>    WARNING: Avoid semver ranges starting with '>' in engines.node
>    WARNING: App Management cannot be installed because the start script cannot be found.
> ```

My start script is located in Procfile at my project root and contains which is starting my project ok.

> web: gulp serve:prod

I tried putting a start command in package.json but still had this same warning. How can I get App Management installed?

Comment: Are you sure gulp is installed and in the path on the server you're deploying to?

Comment: Can you post your package.json file? This is what these errors are likely referring to

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I am having the same error today

Comment: The answer from Sai is the right approach. I changed my start script in package.json to start the application directly.

`"start": "node ./dist/server/app.js"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Management in the IBM Node.js buildpack currently only supports applications that are started using the `node` executable with a JS file. For example,

```
node [opts] server.js [args]
```

This is because many utilities in App Management are dependent on being able to manipulate the start command.  For example, to start the application with inspector enabled, we need to be able to set the debug port (`--debug $PORT`).

Due to this limitation, App Management is not supported if your application uses gulp or similar build automation systems to start your application.